# Unexpected sort order in en_US.UTF-8 locale

Tags: sort, locale, glibc

While trying to answer [this question about SQL sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34537982/50552), I noticed a `sort` order I did not expect:

```
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8  
$ echo "T-700A Grouped" > sort.txt
$ echo "T-700 AGrouped" >> sort.txt
$ echo "T-700A Halved" >> sort.txt
$ echo "T-700 Whole" >> sort.txt
$ cat sort.txt | sort
T-700 AGrouped
T-700A Grouped
T-700A Halved
T-700 Whole
$
```

Why is `700 A` sorted above `700A`, while `700A` is above `700 W` ?  I would expect a space to come before `A` consistently, independent of the characters following it.

It works fine if you use the C locale:

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ echo "T-700A Grouped" > sort.txt
$ echo "T-700 AGrouped" >> sort.txt
$ echo "T-700A Halved" >> sort.txt
$ echo "T-700 Whole" >> sort.txt
$ cat sort.txt | sort
T-700 AGrouped
T-700 Whole
T-700A Grouped
T-700A Halved
$
```

Comment: It appears that leading whitespace is ignored and trailing whitespace isn't.

Comment: @MichaelHomer: You're right, my mistake, typoed "A" for "A<space>". I'll update the question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sorting is done in multiple passes.  Each character has three (or sometimes more) weights assigned to it.  Let's say for this example the weights are

```
         wt#1 wt#2 wt#3
space = [0000.0020.0002]
A     = [1BC2.0020.0008]
```

To create the sort key, the nonzero weights of the characters of a string are concatenated, one weight level at a time.  That is, if a weight is zero, no corresponding weight is added (as can be seen at the beginning for `" A"`).  So

```
       wt#1   -- wt#2 ---   -- wt#3 ---
" A" = 1BC2   0020   0020   0002   0008
       A      sp     A      sp     A

       wt#1   wt#2   wt#3
"A"  = 1BC2   0020   0008
       A      A      A

       wt#1   -- wt#2 ---   -- wt#3 ---
"A " = 1BC2   0020   0020   0008   0002
       A      A      sp     A      sp
```

If you sort these arrays you get the order you see:

```
       1BC2   0020   0008               => "A"
       1BC2   0020   0020   0002   0008 => " A"
       1BC2   0020   0020   0008   0002 => "A "
```

This is a simplification of what actually happens; see the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/) for more details.  The above example weights are actually from the standard table, with some details omitted.

Comment: Very helpful.  The fact that it sorts A-Space above Space-A above W-Space cannot be explained by a constant code point for space. As you suggest it is probably multiple passes, which section 1.6 seems to explain.

Comment: I am a bit lost here: why `A` becomes `A A A` , why ` A` becomes `A sp A sp A`, why `A ` becomes `A A sp A sp`  ?  and why those `A` are of weight `1BC2` ? and why `sp` is sometimes weight `0020` and sometimes `0002` ? Please explain a bit more for me :)