# How can I debug or trace sorting for "LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 ls -l"?

Tags: ls, filenames, sort, unicode, gnu

([Unexpected sort order in en_US.UTF-8 locale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252419/unexpected-sort-order-in-en-us-utf-8-locale/252426#252426) explains the basics of UTF sorting)

Consider this test scenarion:

```
# touch abc{.{g,t,t.t},@.s,-{s-w,t.c}}
# LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" ls -l test
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  8 08:52 abc.g
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  8 08:52 abc@.s
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  8 08:52 abc-s-w
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  8 08:52 abc.t
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  8 08:52 abc-t.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  8 08:52 abc.t.t
```

I had expected that either "all dots" or "all minuses" are sorted first, but the result looks like a funny mixture.  Software packages being used were

```
coreutils-8.25-13.7.1.x86_64
glibc-2.22-100.8.1.x86_64
glibc-locale-2.22-100.8.1.x86_64
```

Using `LC_COLLATE=POSIX` results in "correct" sorting:

```
# ls -l test
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  8 08:52 abc-s-w
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  8 08:52 abc-t.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  8 08:52 abc.g
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  8 08:52 abc.t
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  8 08:52 abc.t.t
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  8 08:52 abc@.s
```

Some details:

```
# locale -k LC_COLLATE
collate-nrules=0
collate-rulesets=""
collate-symb-hash-sizemb=0
collate-codeset="ANSI_X3.4-1968"
# LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" locale -k LC_COLLATE
collate-nrules=4
collate-rulesets=""
collate-symb-hash-sizemb=2707
collate-codeset="UTF-8"
```

Is there a way to have the sorting "explained" like some verbose trace or debug messages?  It does not have to be for the `ls` command, but some simple demonstration code would be fine, too.

Is there a safe alternative for UTF-8 and `LC_COLLATE` that sorts "more traditional", meaning: Can I safely use `LC_COLLATE=POSIX` instead?

Comment: The *reason* for that order is that `-` and `.` are just ignored, at least while there are other differences. I don't know of a tool that produces collation weights for arbitrary strings and locales, though, or a common UTF-8 locale that sorts lexicographically by codepoint or similar. What kind of ordering do you want?

Comment: As I wrote: either "all minus first" or "all dots first", but not a mixture. Isn't the idea of sorting to speed up finding?